# Mongo convert array of strings to ObjectId and then delete them

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, delete-row

I have an array of strings of ids, which I am trying to make it first an array of ObjectIds and then using those ObjectIds need to delete those records from the collection.

```
arrOfStr = ['6346ed8f0c2437c710321c4e','6346ed8f0c2437c710321c4f', '6346ed8f0c2437c710321c50', '6350ccf90720be117781a746']
```

In Mongo Shell trying the loop to convert the strings to ObjectId but it return as blank.

```
for (i=0;i < arrOfStr.length;i++) {
  const query = {_id: ObjectId(arrOfStr[i])}
  console.log(query)
}
```

Output:

```
{ _id: {} }
```

Expecting:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("6350ccf90720be117781a746") }
```

What I can do here to get the ObjectId and then use the query to delete a record?

Comment: when I `printjson(query)` it shows what you are expecting

Comment: @Usama 
for (i=0;i < arrOfStr.length;i++) {
  const query = {_id: ObjectId(arrOfStr[i])}
  printjson(query)
}
{ _id: {} }
{ _id: {} }
{ _id: {} }
{ _id: {} }

Comment: dont know why, I am running in both Studio 3T and Robo 3T and its showing correct output

Comment: @Usama I am trying on atlas mongo shell

Comment: Try manually: `console.log(ObjectId('6346ed8f0c2437c710321c4e'))`

Answer (score 0):

You use `$in` operator and delete all of them with one query:

```
db.collection.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: arrOfStr.map((item) => ObjectId(item) }});
```

Comment: You're missing the actual `$in` in the code snippet I think